# YouTube на сайте. Нагрузка на чей сервер?

Tags: веб-сервер, youtube

Подскажите, нагрузка на сервер будет меньше, если видео на сервере располагать встроенное с YouTube или всё же одинаково? Считаю что трафик будет уходить на YouTube сервера, а значит и нагрузка. Поправьте меня если не прав

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы, видео будет загружаться с YouTube, следовательно, ваш сервер задействован в этом процессе не будет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вопрос звучал немного по другому